# Linux file names and tilde--not for home directory--in bash

Tags: linux, bash

I understand the tilde (~) at the end of a file displayed in bash is a backup file in the Linux file system. Is there a way to keep these hidden when listing the contents of a directory?

Comment: That's not defined "in the Linux file system" (there isn't a "Linux file system"). It's just defined by convention, and certain tools assume that's what it means.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"ls -B" will ignore backup files, too.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `ls --hide='*~'` to not show files matching that pattern. You could add an alias for it in your shell's rc file like this:

```
alias ls="ls --hide='*~'"
```

Comment: You mean `alias ls="ls --hide='*~'"`.

Comment: Yes, thanks. Remember both questions and answers here are like wiki pages, you can edit them and fix mistakes yourself. That would have been a good candidate for a quick fix.